# Select data from two tables with Linq/Lambda

Tags: c#, database, linq, lambda

When the customer logs in with Social Security Number to the website I want it to show the customers Accountname, Accountnumber and Balance. These information have to be fetched through database.

Accounts table:

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts] (
[id]            BIGINT       IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[accountnumber] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[accountname]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[SSN]           BIGINT       NOT NULL,
[CustomerId]    INT          NULL,
[balance]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[BalanceId]     INT          NULL,
[AccountId]     INT          NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Accounts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Accounts_dbo.Customer] FOREIGN KEY ([SSN]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([SSN])
 );


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SSN]
ON [dbo].[Accounts]([SSN] ASC);
```

Customer table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer] (
[id]                BIGINT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Firstname]         VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[Lastname]          VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[SSN]               BIGINT          NOT NULL,
[Password]          VARBINARY (MAX) NULL,
[ConfirmPassword]   VARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[Salt]              VARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[AccountId]         INT             NULL,
[BalanceId]         INT             NULL,
[RegPayId]          INT             NULL,
[ConfirmedRegPayId] INT             NULL,
[CustomerId]        INT             NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SSN] ASC)
   );
```

But this code shows me no customer:

```
       List<AccountsCTX> everyBalance = db.Accounts.Join(db.Customer, a => a.id, 
                                                                      c => c.SSN, 
                                                              (a, c) => new AccountsCTX()
        {
            //id = a.id,
            SSN = a.SSN,
            accountname = a.accountname,
            accountnumber = a.accountnumber,
            balance = a.balance
        }
                            ).ToList();
        return everyBalance;
```

I have "id" as the primary key from table "Accounts" and "SSN" as the foreign key from table "Customer".

I'm still freshman in programming so need more practice xD
Let me know for more details and appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: Please don't use images, but plain text. It's in your own interest if a question is easy to read.

Comment: it's easier to show then to explain sometimes =p

Comment: You can show the tables in plain text. Takes a little more effort but it pays off.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
    public static AccountsCTX GetEveryBalance(long currentCustomerSsn)
    { 
     AccountsCTX everyBalance = db.Accounts.Join(db.Customer, a => a.SSN, 
                                                                          c => c.SSN, 
                                                                  (a, c) => new AccountsCTX()
            {
                //id = a.id,
                SSN = a.SSN,
                accountname = a.accountname,
                accountnumber = a.accountnumber,
                balance = a.balance
            }
                                ).Where(x=>x.SSN==currentCustomerSsn).FirstOrDefault();//currentCustomerSsn is enter ssn by Customer
            return everyBalance;
    }

    //Create customer
    public long insertCusReg(CustomerCTX inCusReg)
    {
        ...
        try
        {
            ...
            return inCusReg.SSN;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 0;
        }


    }
```

Call Method

```
currentCustomerSsn=insertCusReg(CustomerCTX);// pass CustomerCTX object 
AccountsCTX everyBalance=GetEveryBalance(currentCustomerSsn);
```

Comment: Same result, nothing appears, wonder if i did something wrong in database or mixed up the keys. But thx for taking your time to help me =D

Comment: Do you want costomer enter your SSN and appear your Accountname, Accountnumber and Balance?

Comment: Yes, e.g. I want Bruce Wayne to enter his SSN so when he is logged in. Only his detail will show up on the page. I have added some screenshot of the tables for better understanding.

Comment: I see you updated your question and I updated my answer

Comment: Yeah and now it shows me all information plus the other customer too. I only want for one spesific customer. We're getting somewhere =D

Comment: **currentCustomerSsn** does not exist in the current context..is the error i get now

Comment: currentCustomerSsn  is User enter ssn

Comment: nope..gave me error all over the place =p
the one @James implemented works ;O)

Comment: what is SSN type?

Comment: **public Int64 SSN { get; set; }**

Comment: My answer code is method. You can call this method pass currentCustomerSsn and you can get Customer info (AccountsCTX object)

Comment: did not quite understand what you mean =p

Comment: almost what i wanted..but i do not want to enter manually a new SSN for every customer is created..i want it to fetch it automatically from database

Comment: How do you know login Customer?

Comment: cause i create one =p

Comment: you can get current customer ssn in you create

Comment: cause i have a method for **create customer** and another for **listing customer information** <--this one you've been helping me with

Comment: You create ssn then select this ssn then pass other method

Comment: sorry, i should have shown this to you from the start, this is how the method looks like:

https://gyazo.com/ae4b9933dc2d0ce4165f9ed29cfffac5

Comment: Can you look my answer?

Comment: how can i return it in your way when my method looks like this?

https://gyazo.com/7976a0150b00cfd3344a7c1473735aa1

Comment: I look you code. This code always return the same customer. ssn=12345678901

Comment: yeah and i want it to return me customer's ssn from database each time i login with different ssn's

Comment: yeah..but now get the error other places..since this project is divided in to small other solutions (DAL, BLL and Model).

this one from BLL:

https://gyazo.com/04f371248fa976289be0b1a19025349d

this one from Controller:

https://gyazo.com/e2013c11921e34f479276d31ee507aac

Comment: is it possible to do what you suggested via Sessions?

like what im trying to do when i want to show customer's name when logged in:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40464809/pass-data-via-sessions-through-different-namespaces?noredirect=1#comment68175936_40464809

Answer (score 1):

actually i dont see any relation between the two tables provided except SSN, this inner join will fetch you all the records which has same SSN id in both the tables:

```
List<AccountsCTX> everyBalance = db.Accounts.Join(db.Customer, a => a.SSN, 
                                                                      c => c.SSN, 
                                                              (a, c) => new AccountsCTX()
        {
            SSN = a.SSN,
            accountname = a.accountname,
            accountnumber = a.accountnumber,
            balance = a.balance
        }).Where(x=>x.SSN==InputSSN).ToList();
        return everyBalance;
```

Comment: Now it shows me all information plus the other customer too. I only want for one spesific customer. We're getting somewhere =D

Comment: since one customer can have multiple account with same SSN number, u can give like the above , and get all the results for a particular SSN

Comment: **InputSSN**  does not exist in the current context..is the error i get now

Comment: what i meant from tht is u need to pass SSN value like from your table - 12345678901 0r 55555555555

Comment: it worked..but if i want to create another customer with another SSN..and log in with newly created SSN..how do i implement that?

Comment: when you login , u will get SSN rit, pass the same , you will get details of tht particular SSN

Comment: i dont want to pass the SSN manually for every new customer..i want it to fetch it automatically from the database..really helping me alot man =D

Comment: yes, but for fetching data from DB, u need to pass some ID to get corresponding data rit?

Comment: yup, thinking of how to implement it in order to let it fetch the current SSN that has been entered to log in

Comment: how you generate SSN number, for new customer?

Comment: public bool insertRegAcc(AccountsCTX inRegAcc)
        {

            var db = new BankContext();
            try
            {
                var newAC = new Accounts()
                {
                    accountnumber = inRegAcc.accountnumber,
                    accountname = inRegAcc.accountname,
                    SSN = inRegAcc.SSN,
                    balance = inRegAcc.balance
                };

                db.Accounts.Add(newAC);//newRp
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;

            }

Comment: ops..would not format as i wish..ill send u a screenshot xD

Comment: how customer log in , if customer is new customer ? with ssn ?

Comment: one more question how the existing customer login?

Comment: what i understood from this, for new customer, first you create a record , then redirect that customer to a new screen with barcode / pass code page for automatic/manual entry for authentication, rit?

Comment: yup..1: create customer..2: login screen usual **user+password**..3: authenticat the user before the customer gets access

Comment: then u may get some unique / ssn number, once you clear the authentication by passing the userid to db, at the same time you can load the account details if you want or after authentication u can ask user to login again with their new ssn number, it completely depend on how you want to implement.

Comment: no since the ssn number are not getting mixed up with authentication..how would u do it? im out of ideas xD

and sorry i showed u the wrong method..this is the right one for creating customer:

https://gyazo.com/7976a0150b00cfd3344a7c1473735aa1

Comment: it depend, for an easy way i would insert and get back the ssn, store into session and if authentication gets success, will read ssn from session and load, but again its completely depend on what you are building, you can always figure out a good and secure way

Comment: this is just for practice and im not going to use it in real life xD 
how can i get the ssn from register-method over to a session..implement it in authentiaction-method and load the ssn? sorry to annoy you with all of this i just so eager to learn xD

Comment: While creating user you are passing ssn rit, u can use the same ssn if the insertion to db is success , store tht to session the same way you storing session user unique key, also when authentication is success , pass that value from session to the linq query

Comment: see what u mean..just thinking how i should get the ssn from register-method (in DAL.cs) to login-method (in Controller.cs) since they are in seperate forms..if u see what i mean?

Comment: Please take a look at why we use , how we use and how we read session, you will get to knw , it's easy,

Comment: i know how it works..like e.g. im working on to show users firstname when they login..like (Welcome, Users firstname here) but im getting null reference so im not passing the right way xD 

getting the firstname from here:

https://gyazo.com/0ceda457d635be5451f742d3af7bb8bc

passing it to here:

https://gyazo.com/5fc821995445336b6bbf4a3fc45938a9

hopefully show up here:

https://gyazo.com/57e0a040a6ed3289f424b3c6df441545

if your out of energy i understand you since u helped me for a looooooong time now xD and i appreciate all the help =D

Comment: uncomment session username in the creation method, then try to get tht in the view, here i am taking abt just user creation part, i hope existing customer it is working fine

Comment: when i uncommented the session username it throws an error **Session does not exist in current context**..problem is i have to pass it through different namespaces..one method is in "Controllers"..other one in "DAL" and the last part is in View for cshtml..not yet still figuring it out xD

Comment: and i also noticed where i have that Session is not a **[HttpPost]** and method is boolean that may be the reason.